# pythonic way store some constant string with some structure

Tags: python

What's the most pythonic way if i want to store some constant string and classify them into different category so that I get get them either individually or as a category.
for example, have a module **direction.py** to store

```
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'
UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'

LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'
UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'

VERTICAL = [LEFT, RIGHT]
HORIZONTAL = [UP, DOWN]
ALL = VERTICAL + HORIZONTAL
```

so i can do

```
import direction

direction.LEFT
>>> 'left'

direction.VERTICAL
>>> ['up', 'down']

direction.ALL
>> ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down']
```

Is this a good pythonic design, or should i create a class? Or is there a better structure to use?

Comment: Seems just fine to me.  Simple, easy to understand and use.

Comment: Agreed.. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary for this situation. Seems easier than making other classes or files, but it should be fine either way you choose to do it

Comment: like how? and how can i group vertical direction and all direction????

Comment: directions = { LEFT : 'left', RIGHT : 'right', UP : 'up', DOWN : 'down' , vertical : [ 'up' , 'down' ] } you can also add key value pairs after:                    directions['horizontal'] =[ directions['left'] , directions['right'] ] or directions['all'] = directions['vertical'] + directions['horizontal']

Comment: how to you share it with many other code? it doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: what do you mean? If imported properly in other files, It should be available.But if the goal is to ultimately use this collection in many files, you can store directions either as you did either as a dictionary, even as a lis

Comment: can you give an example